# Kindly provide the stepwise solution for this integral.

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{-b}^b\int_{-a}^a\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+h^2)^{3/2}}dxdy$$

First I put x=$\sqrt{y^2+h^2}tan\theta$ and arrive at: 
$$\int_{-b}^b\frac{2a}{(y^2+h^2)(y^2+h^2+a^2)^{1/2}}dy$$

Can you please tell me what to do after this?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to let $u=y/\sqrt{y^2+h^2+a^2}$? Also, as you have written your first integral the limits for $x$ is $-b$ and $b$. If that is not intended, then you might want to update your question with the different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ a\,,\ b > 0~}}$ and
>   $\ds{\pars{p \equiv {a \over \verts{h}} > 0\,,\
> q \equiv {b \over \verts{h}} > 0}}$:

$$
\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-b}^{b}{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + h^{2}}^{3/2}} =
{4 \over \verts{h}}\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{q}\int_{0}^{p}{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}^{3/2}}}}
$$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{q}\int_{0}^{p}{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}^{3/2}}}} \,\,\,\stackrel{y\ \mapsto\ {1/y}}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{p}\int_{1/q}^{\infty}{y\,\dd y \over
\bracks{\pars{x^{2} + 1}y^{2} + 1}^{3/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{y^{2}\ \mapsto\ y}{=} &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{p}\int_{1/q^{2}}^{\infty}{\dd y \over
\bracks{\pars{x^{2} + 1}y + 1}^{3/2}}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{p}{1 \over x^{2} + 1}\left.%
{1 \over \bracks{\pars{x^{2} + 1}y + 1}^{1/2}}
\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ 1/q^{2}}^{\ y\ \to\ \infty}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
q\int_{0}^{p}{1 \over x^{2} + 1}
{1 \over \bracks{\pars{x^{2} + 1} + q^{2}}^{1/2}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ {1/x}}{=}\,\,\,
q\int_{1/p}^{\infty}
{x\,\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + 1}\bracks{\pars{q^{2} + 1}x^{2} + 1}^{1/2}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2}\,q\int_{1/p^{2}}^{\infty}
{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\bracks{\pars{q^{2} + 1}x + 1}^{1/2}}
\end{align}

> With the change of variable
>   $\ds{x \equiv {t^{2} - 1 \over q^{2} + 1}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{q}\int_{0}^{p}{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}^{3/2}}}} =
q\int_{\root{p^{2} + q^{2} + 1}/p}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + q^{2}} =
{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{\root{p^{2} + q^{2} + 1} \over pq}
\\[5mm] = &\
\arctan\pars{pq \over \root{p^{2} + q^{2} + 1}}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-b}^{b}{\dd x\,\dd y \over
\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} + h^{2}}^{3/2}} =
{4 \over h}\,\arctan\pars{ab/h \over \root{a^{2} + b^{2} + h^{2}}}}}
$$

Comment: Now that after 7 years I am doing something worthwhile and not wasting my time, I had been stuck in this problem for 2 days and I felt very discouraged. I know this is too much but thank you. You saved me from giving up.

Comment: @BeckHumh Thanks. I'm glad it was useful. Something I always check at the beginning is the change $x \mapsto 1/x$. It yields many surprises.

Answer (score 0):

If we substitute
$$y=\sqrt{a^2+h^2}\tan u$$
$$dy=\sqrt{a^2+h^2}\sec^2u \text{ }du$$
We get the integral
$$\int \frac{2a(\sqrt{a^2+h^2}\sec^2u)}{((a^2+h^2)\tan^2u+h^2)((a^2+h^2)\tan^2u+a^2+h^2)^{1/2}}du$$
Remembering that $\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$, we get
$$\int \frac{2a\sqrt{a^2+h^2}\sec^2u}{((a^2+h^2)\sec^2u -h^2)((a^2+h^2)\sec^2u)^{1/2}}du$$ 
Now you can simplify quite a bit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this substitution, so Readers can more quickly understand where it leads?

Comment: Okay. I will edit the post.